# Run ansible via command line using with_items

Tags: ansible

I have item list of IPs:

```
server_hosts:
        - { host: '1.1.1.1' }
        - { host: '10.10.10.10' }
```

I want to pass only one of the items in the command line:

```
ansible-playbook base.yml -i ${host}, --extra-vars "env_name=lab server_hosts={host:'${1.1.1.1}'} "
```

but this gives an error of:

> {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'host'\n\nThe error

Any advice how to pass a specific item from list in the command line?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you also revealed what shell you were using, because bash will stumble on this command. Yet `${host}` looks bash-like.

Comment: the command is editted here, but it passes and run the pre tasks ( from jenkins) but fail on the task using the list items

Comment: I repeat: bash will return `bad substitution` when you try to execute it. Please edit your question to include a verifiable example. Right now it's a pure fabrication and you are only wasting readers' time.

Comment: Not to mention the title has nothing to do with the content of the question. You don't even bother to show what you run `with_items`.

Comment: I have removed the host from
server_hosts:
        - { host: '1.1.1.1' }
        - { host: '10.10.10.10' }
and this accepted the server_hosts='{1.1.1.1}' in the cmd.
FYI

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to a side note [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line):

> **Note:** Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).

So, you should use:

```
--extra-vars '{"env_name":"lab","server_hosts":{"host":"1.1.1.1"}}'
```

Otherwise you end up with `server_hosts` as string, not an object.